# Rows not getting full width inside Column in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, jetpack

I have column having size of 80dp and i set it to maxWidth and inside column i have two Rows i have equally divided both using weight(1f) but its not getting full width.

[image: preview]

Current Output

```
Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .size(80.dp)
            .background(Color.Transparent)
            .border(1.dp, colorGreyLight, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f)
                .background(colorPrimary),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ){

        }
        Row(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f)
                .background(Color.Black),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ){

        }
}
```

Comment: can you share more code with parent composable as well so the reason can be traced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code which work for me.

Preview
[image: preview]

Code

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Stack022(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(80.dp)
            .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            .border(2.dp, Color.Gray, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)),
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f)
                .background(Color.Red),
        ) {

        }
        Row(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f)
                .background(Color.Black),
        ) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Chirag,  this worked for me.   i was passing padding to parent composable which effect the inner padding.  now i pass padding inside column which work as a margin :)

Comment: @MujeeburRahman If this answer resolved your issue, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the green checkmark to the left of it.